# Spark hangs. No jobs are executed for minutes

Tags: apache-spark

we run a Spark 1.6.1 application. 
At some point I see no more jobs being submitted. No cores active even though cores are available and the driver stdout/stderr prints nothing.
This situation lasts for minutes until it magically submit a new job, it is shown by the Spark UI and the cores are assigned to tasks.

What is spark doing? 
I thought it could be the DAG generation but this looks to be dependent on the size of the input data.

**EDIT**

Managed to solve this. Who has written the code has used a foldleft passing a df which resulted in the df being converted at the driver.

Comment: Did you check the driver log4j to see what it was trying to do? At times, even though it appears that the cluster is idiling, you might notice SQL subtab shows a particular SQL is active waiting for job impl.

Comment: The SQL tab is empty. If by driver log4j you mean the driver stdout/stderr links in executors page, yes I have checked. Nothing is printed until execution resumes.

Comment: Managed to solve this. Who has written the code has used a foldleft passing a df which resulted in the df being converted at the driver.

Comment: Glad it is resolved! The stdout should have captured that it is retrieving the data. In any case, you might want to enable verbose gc logging. With that, one can at least check if JVM is doing something. To go one level deeper, use JMX.